# What happens to namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

when a dll is created out of the  source code in a given namespaces a,b with functions a::open,b::open will there be any conflict in calling these function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the function names exported from the DLLs are the C++ mangled names. The mangled names include the namespace, so there will be no conflict.

Comment: Just as you said in your question: a::open() or b::open().  No problems as long as you have the header files; otherwise you cannot call them at all.

Comment: The problem might be in GetProcAddress, which doesn't like mangled names.

Comment: GetProcAddress is agnostic about mangled names - as long as you give it a correctly mangled name, it will give you back the correct function.